# Evaluate Code / Mentoring

Tags: discussion

I am trying to learn programming on my own and only for fun, and would like to have my code reviewed after some exercises in the book. What is the best way to show you my code for it to be evaluated?

Is this even the right platform or would you defer me to a forum like code ranch? I haven't had a pleasant experience with that particular forum before.

Comment: there's a stack exchange site for code reviews: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I cringe at the advice given here.  A web site is never, and will never be, a substitute for a tutor that patiently explains how to do it better or a friend that learns the ropes at the same speed.  The kind of people that care to help.  Becoming a professional programmer requires learning a skill set that's comparable in size to what a lawyer or surgeon needs to learn to do his job.  Without the benefit of 100 year dusty old books that cover the basics.  Advice like this just devalues the profession.

Comment: I took classes at my community college. This is far more valuable.

Answer (score 10):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a site for you. When posting a question there, make sure that:

- Your question contains code that you have written
- The code works (Please test it for a bit)
- It is **not** "example code" (Did you simplify identifiers before posting? We don't like that on Code Review. URLs, passwords and stuff can of course be anonymized)
- Describe what the code does (Yes yes, we know how to read code, but we can give you help faster, and better help, if you provide a pure-english part of your question with a description of what the code is meant to do)

Adhere to these points and you will likely find a home at Code Review. I know I did.

Comment: Thank you, Simon! I will be sure to do that. What do you mean by simplifying identifiers? Also when do I post on Stack Overflow instead of Code Review?

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz Simplified description: Stack Overflow is for code that **does not work** or for **specific problems** that you encounter while coding. By simplifying identifiers I mean that you change your variable name `myInterestingVariable` to `foo` or `someValue` or similar

Answer (score 3):

> *"Is this even the right platform or would you defer me to a forum like code ranch? I haven't had a pleasant experience with that particular forum before."*

Stack Overflow usually isn't the right platform to ask for tutoring you about broad topics or programming languages (also note SE sites aren't meant to be *"forums"*).

As mentioned in comments, asking your question at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be appropriate under certain conditions.

Certainly questions asking for a detailed guidance about learning a specific language feature or detail are not on-topic. Those should be closed as being *"too broad"*, may be along with some link to the reference documentation of the language in question.